# Upload and process KML file in Google AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-upload

I haven't been able to find the exact answer to this question.

In my app I want the user to be able to upload a KML file using an HTML form. On the server side, I want to parse that file and pull out certain information (lat, lon, etc) to be stored in a database.

In my HTML form I have

```
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40" />
```

On the server side, I'm getting an error from the parse, ostensibly because the file is being seen as the filename string, not as a file, so there is nothing to parse.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I needed to put a enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute on my form tag. Then in the POST method, simply call self.request.get("datafile"). This returns the xml string, which I simply needed to pass to parseString().

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the blobstore docs:  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html

There is an example there that is similar to what you are doing.  In the UploadHandler, you could do the KML processing that you want to do.  If it will take a long time to process a gigantic KML file, you might consider just allowing the file to be saved in the blobstore, and starting a Task that does the actual processing.  (I did a similar thing with CSV files.)

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. My file is pretty short (~50 lines). I did figure out what I did wrong (see below).